# How to fix my Pycharm Anaconda edition installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I download the package .tar.gz of the Profesional with Anaconda version from the Pycharm Web: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/promo/anaconda/

I followed some instructions that said:

1. Unpackage
2. From the terminal, inside the `/bin` folder of that unpackaged file, run the command `./pycharm.sh`

It seems worked correctly, and I could open it and introduce my activation code. I was coding well with Pycharm.

After reboot, I write in the Ubuntu search bar 'Pycharm', but it doesn't find it, and only offer me to install different versions from the 'Ubuntu Software' app.

I was trying some things and I could open the app again, but I'm not sure how I did it. I can't anchor the app to the dock because it doesn't give me the option.

I have looked for the installation folder in '/opt' and '/usr/bin' but I didn't find it.

I'm suspecting that I have opened the program from the unpackaged folder.

Any idea about how to solve it? I'm a noob in Linux.

Comment: Add that `bin` folder to your path.

Comment: Could you tell me how? and what that means? is it the launcher of the app?

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: Thanks, now I know what PATH is. Then, what is what you propose? To move the `bin` folder of the unpackaged file or ad the path of this to the `$PATH`? the unpackaged folder is in desktop, and I'm not sure how to move the `bin` folder (have I to just move it?) PD: I can't vote this commentaries, only answers.

Comment: The instructions are at [Install PyCharm - Help | PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html?section=Linux#windowsAnaconda). If you follow those then afterwards add `/opt/pycharm-*/bin` to your path following the instructions in the first link I gave you.